# Where can I learn about complicated WPF binding?

Tags: wpf, binding

Recently, I've started working with WPF, and I'm asking a lot of what I think are basic questions about databinding. I don't 'get' it yet; why one thing works and not another (for seemingly voodoo reasons), how I accomplish what I want to do, and what everything means *precisely*.

There's lots of tutorials out there that go over the simple basics, but I can't find any that cover things similar to the more complicated examples that I'm trying to do. I don't want to create lots of toy apps, I want to *understand what on earth is going on* and *what everything means*. Where can I learn this?

Comment: Have you considered simpler binding alternatives like this http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2012/08/simpler-wpf-binding.html - WPF allows you to extend and even potentially replace the default WPF binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick up a copy of [Pro WPF in C# 2010](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430272052)

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing where you've already looked makes it a bit harder to recommend anything, but I started with two items on The Code Project, 1 from [Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GuidedTourWPF_1.aspx) and 1 from [Sacha Barber](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF1.aspx). From there, I read a lot of Josh's blog posts, and eventually bought [WPF Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917).

Answer (score 0):

It is a question everyone who have been in your situation ask themselves, often with elevated blood pressure and frustrated jaw syndrome.

The answer is of course just to plow on, do it and do it some other way;
it's steep, but it's pretty fun, once you get over the most new-agy part of WPF in general,
and the design pattern adherence mental debate it very often leads to.

Answer (score 0):

I find this cheat-sheet very useful: http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf